# Undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass — throws error in view but works in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code keeps throwing a NoMethodError when I try to load. It was working earlier until I reset my database:

```
<% pstate= Place.where(statename: @agency.state) %>
<% fips_place = pstate.where(placeshort: @agency.city) %>
<%= place = 'PLACE:' + fips_place.first.placefp %>
```

But it works fine in the console when I run:

```
> pstate = Place.where(statename: "CA")
> fips_place = pstate.where(placeshort: "Los Angeles")
> place = "PLACE: " + fips_place.first.placefp
=> "PLACE: 85292"
```

controllers/agencies_controller.rb:

```
def set_agency
    @agency = Agency.find(params[:id])
end
```

models/agency.rb:

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :place
    ...
end
```

model/place.rb:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :agency
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm getting an error! I don't know why.

Comment: What are values for \@agency.state and \@agency.city in the code?

Comment: `@agency = Agency.find(params[:id])`. In the table, the values are generally something like `CA` and `Los Angeles`, `LA` and `Baton Rouge`, etc. It's also only throwing this error for some `:id`s, but not all. Los Angeles, CA is working fine, for instance, but Anchorage, AK doesn't.

Comment: What error (exactly) does it throw?

Comment: NoMethodError at /agencies/1
undefined method `placefp' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that there is no row in the places table whose `statename` and `placeshort` match `@agency.state` and `@agency.city`.

So then `fips_place.first` returns nil, and your attempt to call `placefp` causes the error.

It works in the console because you're using different values for `statename` and `placeshort`.

Comment: Aha! Bingo. It wasn't working because the `placeshort` value for the `@agency` I was trying to call in the browser (Anchorage, AK, in this case) was `Anchorage Municipality` and not `Anchorage`. (And it was working before I reset my database because I caught it and fixed it before. HA.) Thank you!